# Please set python.buildPython to your Python executable path

Tags: chaquopy

I try to run code from this repository: https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy
But I have an error: 
'py -3' failed to start (org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'py''). Please set python.buildPython to your Python executable path.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaquopy needs Python to be installed on your build machine in order to build the app. If you don't already have it installed, I recommend the official Windows Python release from python.org, which will put the "py" launcher on your PATH by default.

Or if you have Python installed somewhere else, use the `buildPython` setting to tell Chaquopy where to find it, as described [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython).

Answer (score 1):

```
defaultConfig {
    python {
        buildPython "C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe"
    }
}
```

"buildPython" is the exact path to the python executable.

Answer (score 0):

**First check your path of python IDE if you haven't install it then install it and then copy that path and paste like below in your gradle.buld inside the defaultConfig **

```
   configuration =[
           pythonPath : "C:\\Users\\Mazhar Iqbal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe"
   ]
```